# Stretching controls to fill ItemsControl

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

I am attempting to write a simple WPF learning project which creates a set of buttons inside a resizeable main window.  There is to be one `Button` per entry in a collection, and the contents of that collection may vary during run-time.  I want the buttons to fill the entire window (e.g. 1 button @ 100% width, 2 buttons @ 50% width, 3 buttons @ 33% width, etc. all at 100% height).  A simplified version of what I've written so far is:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemscontrolButtons" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Button Tag="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
      </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
...    
List<string> listButtonTexts = new List<string>() { "Button1", "Button2" };
...
itemscontrolButtons.DataContext = listButtonTexts;
```

This results in this:

[image]

I have been unable to make the buttons stretch to fit the width and my attempts to use a `Grid` instead of `StackPanel` were fruitless.

Then, as an optional improvement, I would appreciate suggestions on how to adjust it such that if there are so many buttons that they cannot fit properly on a line or are narrower than a threshold, it will wrap onto a new line (thereby halving the button heights if going from 1 to 2 rows).

I'd like to emphasize that I'd like to know how to do this the *WPF way*.  I realize I can consume window resize messages and resize the controls explicitly, and that's how I'd have done it with MFC or WinForms, but from what I've read that is not how such things should be done with WPF.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Replace the item control's panel with a UniformGrid, this will size all children so everything fits exactly:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks to Nir's answer, I was able to fulfill the optional criterion.  Details are in the answer I've posted to this question.  It was recommended on Meta that I handle this situation this way.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/my-improved-answer-based-on-anothers-accepted-answer-for-my-own-question

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was missing for spacing items and their panel evenly in a listbox.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to build on Nir's answer to fulfill my optional criterion allowing for WPF-managed stretching with multiple rows.

First you must be able to alter the properties of the template *UniformGrid*.  To do that you need to store a reference to it.  There are [multiple methods for accomplishing this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/efaf9cb8-667b-4299-a25e-378ef0b8a02d).  I chose to handle the *Loaded* event for the *UniformGrid* and store a reference at that time.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <UniformGrid Rows="1" Loaded="UniformGrid_Loaded" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

And in the code behind:

```
UniformGrid uniformgridButtons;
private void UniformGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  uniformgridButtons = sender as UniformGrid;
}
```

Then, handle the *SizeChanged* event and adjust the rows parameter according to whatever criteria you wish.

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if ((uniformgridButtons != null) && (this.Width > 0))
  {
    // Set row count according to your requirements
    uniformgridButtons.Rows = (int)(1 + ((this.MinWidth * iButtonCount) / this.Width));
  }
}
```

So this allows WPF to manage the stretching like in Nir's answer, but allows you to explicitly adjust the number of rows.  The above code gives this result:

[image]

(Animated sample [here](http://img149.imageshack.us/img149/1195/sequence01.gif))

---

**Update 2009/08/28:**

I was adjusting my learning application so that the `ItemsControl` was in a `DataTemplate` in a separate `ResourceDictionary`.  However, events such as `Loaded` cannot be handled in an external `ResourceDictionary` XAML file because it has no code-behind (usually).  Therefore, I needed to cache the reference to the `UniformGrid` using a different technique.

I instead used [Alan Haigh's `FindItemsPanel` method (10th reply)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/efaf9cb8-667b-4299-a25e-378ef0b8a02d).  First, I replaced the `ItemsControl` with :

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="contentpresenterButtons" Content="{Binding obscolButtons}" />
```

Then in my `ResourceDictionary`, I put the `ItemsControl` in the `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Buttons}">
  <ItemsControl ... 
</DataTemplate>
```

Finally, I stored the reference to the templated `UniformGrid` as so:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  uniformgridButtons = FindItemsPanel<UniformGrid>(contentpresenterButtons);
  // Also call the code in Window_SizeChanged which I put in another method
}
```

This works just the same as my previous solution but without requiring an event handler in the `ResourceDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- width must be explicitly set for this example -->
<StackPanel 
    Name="MyStack" 
    Orientation="Horizontal"
    Width="250"
    Load="Window_Loaded"> 
    <Button/>
    <Button/>
    <Button/>
</StackPanel>
```

---

```
public void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UIElementCollection elements = MyStack.Children;
    int count = elements.Count;

    foreach (UIElement element in elements)
    {
        if (element is Button)
            ((Button)element).Width = MyStack.Width / count;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my post only 20 minutes before you responded to explain that I wanted to avoid explicitly setting the width.  I'm sorry I should have thought to include that requirement initially.  Explicitly managing the dimensions like this (and by handling resize messages as well) may be necessary for my secondary requirement, if WrapPanel were to be used.  Thanks.