# ItemsControl same sized Items

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

this is my first post here, so be tolerant for any possible mistakes I made here ;)

I am building an App where I want to have a tab Layout. So I am currently using this code:

```
<Grid Margin="0,97,0,0" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ItemsControl Margin="0,0,0,0" x:Name="itemsControl" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding name}" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
    <FlipView x:Name="flipView" Margin="0,147,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding groups}">
        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding articles}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding category}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"/>
                                <Image Source="{Binding image}"></Image>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
```

I would like the Items to fill the width of the ItemsControl and be equally sized.

Thank You.
Luca

**Edit:**
Just to better explain what I want to archieve:
[I want tabs looking like the "365 Steps", "News", "Event", "Archiv" tabs in the Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uRsW.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270078/stretching-controls-to-fill-itemscontrol

Comment: No it is not, because I'm developing an universal app. Some of the Panels aren't available here like the DockPanel or UniformGrid, which are suggested in the thread you've linked to.

Comment: For starters, you might add some ColumnDefinition's to your Item's Grid so your Category, Title, and Image don't just stack on top of another. Then try also adding something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067309/listviewitem-wont-stretch-to-the-width-of-a-listview) just for starters.

Comment: Which `ItemsControl`? The `itemsControl` one? Or the `flipView` (which is also `ItemsControl`)? "Equally sized" how? Width? Height? Both? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've got so far, along with a precise description of what that code does now, and what you'd like it to do instead.

Comment: why are you using an ItemsControl  for the header aren't those item supposed to be fix? why you won't simply define a Grid with multiple columns instead ?

Comment: No these Items shall be loaded dynamically from my Binded ItemsSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Pivot to achive something like this:

[image]

In order to do this you can use this code:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="item1" Background="DarkBlue" Tapped="item1_Tapped"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="item2" Background="Orange" Tapped="item2_Tapped"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2" x:Name="item3" Background="DarkGray" Tapped="item3_Tapped"/>
    </Grid>
    <Pivot x:Name="rootPivot" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,52,0,0">
        <PivotItem Margin="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Content of pivot item 1."/>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Margin="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Content of pivot item 2."/>
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Margin="0">
            <Grid Background="LightGray">
                <TextBlock Text="Content of pivot item 3."/>
            </Grid>
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

item_Tapped() event handler:

```
private void item3_Tapped( object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e )
{
    rootPivot.SelectedIndex = 2;
}
```

Comment: you can improve this by getting rid of the sizechanged by using grid/column with width all equal to "*".  see my answer for that technique. nice answer though, so i upvoted it.  welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a complete example on how to do this here: https://blog.hompus.nl/2015/09/04/responsive-pivot-headers-in-universal-windows-platform-apps/

Import parts are

```
<Setter Target="HeaderClipper.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
```

- Setting the HorizontalContentAllignment to get the centering
- Taking care of the incorrect default height of a pivot header! The
  default template has 48 set as height and that would not be enough in
  most cases!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers with using Pivot are probably the direction you might go.  If you wanted to play around a bit you could create your own, but you might sacrifice some ability to have what the Pivot offers you automatically.

I totally threw this together in like 5 minutes to demonstrate how you can create your own UI for what you want.  I did not put in anything like bindings, optimize how the menu would use a single property and converter detect which highlight to show, etc.

[image: Simple Menu]

XAML

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Tapped="OnTapped" Tag="0">
            <TextBlock Text="365 Steps" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,6"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="R0"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Tapped="OnTapped" Tag="1">
            <TextBlock Text="News" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,6"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="R1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="2" Tapped="OnTapped" Tag="2">
            <TextBlock Text="Event" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,6"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="R2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="3" Tapped="OnTapped" Tag="3">
            <TextBlock Text="Archive" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,6"/>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="R3" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="MyList">
        <ListBoxItem>Foo</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Bar</ListBoxItem>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Code

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        R0.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        R1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        R2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        R3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = sender as Grid;
        string tag = grid.Tag as string;
        // do more stuff depending on tag
        switch (int.Parse(tag))
        {
            case 0:
                R0.Visibility = Visibility;
                R1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                R2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                R3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                MyList.DataContext = null;  // todo: SET TO YOUR DATA MODEL
                break;

            case 1:
                R1.Visibility = Visibility;
                R0.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                R2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                R3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is not meant as a complete solution, just a jump start on and idea you can inspire from.  Depends on your project, intended audience, and many other factors for what design is best for your case.